# How to name the input parameter to the else statement in a DataWeave match operator?

Tags: if-statement, match, dataweave

How can I rename the $ in the else statement of a DataWeave match operator?

```
payload match {
    case strPayload is String -> "Payload is a String: " ++ strPayload
    else -> $

}
```

One way is to avoid else and use a final always true case:

```
payload match {
    case strPayload is String -> "Payload is a String: " ++ strPayload
    case final if(true) -> final   
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to rename it? The reason maybe useful to understand the problem.

Comment: We often like to name the parameters in lambda expressions to provide context and to make code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
payload match {
    case strPayload is String -> "Payload is a String: " ++ strPayload
    else  other -> other
}
```